# Solve Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.getStarImports()Ljava/util/List;

Tags: java, groovy

I am encountering this exception.

```
Exception :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.getStarImports()Ljava/util/List;
```

I have tried various version of groovy jars like groovy 1.8.4, groovy 1.8.6 etc. But I am not able to get rid of this error.

Comment: Did you check 1.8.2 https://github.com/krsmes/GroovyBukkit/issues/1

Comment: What are you doing that causes the exception?

Comment: Paste a snippet of source code that causes this problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happened to me when I had 2 different versions of Groovy in the classpath at the same time. Check your classpath especially if using something that obfuscates it such as Eclipse or Maven.

In my specific case, I was trying to use Groovy 1.8.6 but a Maven dependency was dragging in 1.6.5 causing errors. It worked fine running unit tests on the command line, but not from within Eclipse.

Comment: in my case it was a conflict between Maven `gmaven-plugin` 1.5 and `groovy-all` 2.0.1. I downgraded `groovy-all` to 1.7.5 and solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too. When I removed one of the jar files everything was fine.

Answer (score 8):

To compile with Groovy 2.x, try adding this to the gmaven plugin element:

```
<configuration>
    <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
    <source>2.0</source>
</configuration>
```

For example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
                <source>2.0</source>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

with

```
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by refreshing all Gradle projects within IntelliJ, and running again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is definitely with multiple groovy versions. I was facing this issue with maven project and Eclipse IDE. In my case, `pom.xml` had the following -

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

But in Eclipse Under Window -> preference -> groovy version was 2.5.0. I downgraded it to 2.3.11 and it worked. Just click on switch to use a lower version of Groovy in Eclipse.

[image]