# Grails- NoSuchMethodError plus(Ljava/util/List;Lja

Tags: grails, gradle

I have updated my grails application from 3.1.9 to 3.2.6 and I am having below exception when running application.

```
| Error Gradle build terminated with error: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/List; (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.moveOriginalCodeToNewMethod(TransactionalTransform.groovy:309)
    at org.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.weaveTransactionalMethod(TransactionalTransform.groovy:194)
    at org.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.weaveTransactionalMethod(TransactionalTransform.groovy:188)
    at org.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.weaveTransactionalBehavior(TransactionalTransform.groovy:141)
    at org.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.visit(TransactionalTransform.groovy:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:178)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:64)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.daemon.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerDaemonServer.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:91)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
| Error Gradle build terminated with error: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/List;
```

Comment: This I think is not application related more desktop environment issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223689/solve-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-codehaus-groovy-ast-modulenode-gets  It does state on the error `Use --verbose to see entire trace.` My point being before you posted this did you spend enough time looking at the actual error message. Development isn't exactly a broadcasting job more a research and undestanding job.

Comment: To further add to my above comment, before you post your next similar issue which has no clue as to underlying issue. I would suggest as a developer what else did you try did you try it under 3.2.5 and 3.2.4 ? was it same behaviour in those what about 3.2.3. You have gone for bleeding edge and haven't done any research yourself into it.